# How chose a certain course and year, and counting how many students studies on this course

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to correct this code so that it chooses a certain course and year, and counts how many students studies on this course. To explain further, it is necessary to enter in the field table YearCourses: course_id, year_id and count_stud (according to this course).
Filds of students: id, name, surname, course_id.

Comment: You should tell us what the current code does not accomplish. From what I can tell most of the queries in your `new` action should be in your `show` action, as that is where you would display the number of students. Please add the name of your `View` as well, such that we may know when it will be shown.

Comment: What's the error / problem?

Comment: Problem in that I can't correctly enter value in the table year_courses. It is brought values course_id, year_id. And here is how it is correct to count how many students for the chosen course - I don't know. That is (with select)
 I choose a course in form - and automatically in the field of count_stud the number of students which has to correspond to this course changes.

Comment: you want how many students from a choose course ?

Comment: Yes. I want to choose course and write to table count of students appropriate this course.

Comment: I am still guessing as I cannot see all that will happen. Your form calls out to a JavaScript function when you submit it. Could you provide the code? Maybe we could see what it tries to post.

Comment: OK, so you have shown us your `_form` partial (which I should have guessed, stupid me), but which `view`-template do you use to render it from in the context of your question?